# MySQL Max Average grouped by 2 fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do the following. I have this table `x`:

```
 id  | rssi | Loc 

 160 | -83  |51      
 160 | -61  |51     
 161 | -80  |51  
 163 | -81  |51  
 161 | -88  |52  
 161 | -82  |53
```

I would like to get the maximum average grouped by id for each of the `Loc`. In other words, I want to do an average grouped by `Loc`,`id` and then from it getting the max `Loc` and its `id`for each `Loc`.
The result would be something like this:

```
id  | maxAvg | Loc 

160 | -72    | 51    
163 | -81    | 52  
161 | -82    | 53
```

I have tried it so far:

```
SELECT loc, id, avg(rssi) as w FROM x
group by loc, id
```

This first part is doing the average of rssi grouping per loc and id but later here is where I am a little bit lost:

> Select Loc, id, Max(t.w)
>   FROM (SELECT t.Loc, t.id, avg (rssi) as w
>   FROM x group by
>   Loc, id) t
>   group by t.Loc
>   order by t.Loc asc;

I don't know if it is the right approach. Any help would be more than welcome.
Thanks.

Solved:

```
SELECT t.loc, t.id, t.w 
FROM (SELECT loc, id, avg(rssi) as w
FROM p
group by loc, id order by loc, w desc)
group by t.loc;
```

Comment: I'm a little lost on your table to your goal data selection.  Is this real data?  Where is loc 53 in your table?

Comment: Telling us that "you are a little bit lost" does not give any of us any way to *help you.* What did you receive and what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is tricky!!  Let's walk through it.You can follow along [in this example](http://rextester.com/LYGU26104).

You are getting towards where you need to be.  The difficult part is bringing in the `id` that matches the average that you already calculated.

So the first thing I did was order the results, so that the lowest average appears as the first row of each group:

```
SELECT loc, id, avg(rssi) as w
FROM p
group by loc, id order by loc, w desc;
```

From there I made a quick counter to rank each row, and pulled only the `rank` =1

```
SET @loc = NULL, @currvalue = NULL;

select  id, w,
    @currcount := IF(@loc = loc, @currcount + 1, 1) AS rank,
    @loc := loc AS loc from 
(SELECT loc, id, avg(rssi) as w
FROM p
group by loc, id order by loc, w desc) r
having rank = 1
;
```

This gives you the desired results

Comment: Thanks to you I came up with another possible solution without the counter. It is shorter:                                                                                                                                                           `Select t.loc, t.id, t.w FROM (SELECT loc, id, avg(rssi) as w
FROM p
group by loc, id order by loc, w desc) t                                                                  GROUP BY t.Loc;`                                                                                               Thank you!